# WCF. Multiple HTTP bindings differ only by IP address

Tags: c#, wcf

I have process containing a self-hosted WCF service on port 80 (http binding). I need to be able to run multiple instances of the process. The host machine has multiple IP addresses on 1 NIC. The service URI for each instance of the service only differs by the IP address e.g.

```
Process 1: http://192.168.0.1:80/MyService
Process 2: http://192.168.0.2:80/MyService
```

I thought this should be possible as the URIs are unique and that http allows port sharing with different IP addresses.

When a second process is started I get

```
HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/MyService/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS
```

The '+' in this error suggests that it is trying to bind to port 80 of ALL ip addresses rather than just the one specified.

Is it possible to have WCF bind http to just the one IP address?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer a few minutes after asking the question:

Simply set hostNameComparisonMode="Exact" in the binding in the App.config file